# Calling function in Objective-C from an alertView based function

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

So I have an alert view and when I press enter into the alert view it calls this function:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
     NSString *name = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
    // name contains the entered value
    NSLog(name);
    if(login){
        LoginToProfile(name);
    } else if(createAccount){
        //AddAcount(name);
    }

  }
}
```

Now within this method as you can see I want it to be able to call another function defined in the same view controller that called/created the alert view. But the compiler doesn't like this.

I also get the warning "Implicit declaration of LoginToProfile is invalid in C99".

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: What do you think LoginToProfile is and how have you defined it?

Comment: I defined it in the same file as follows: (right now it's an empty method)


-(void)LoginToProfile:(NSString *)name{
    
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a c-function you have defined. It's an obj-c method which you need to call on the object itself. You call it like this `[self LoginToProfile:name]`

Comment: Syntax is just so different from what I'm used to, it's hard to adjust =)

But yes your answer did help a lot.